# 32bit assembly - correct use of lodsb

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to write in 32bit assembly a function that takes a string and print it character by character using the LODSB instruction.

I'm doing something wrong because I always get a segmentation fault, but actually I don't understand what mistake I've made, I only know that is in the use of LODSB.

Here is my code:

```
CPU X64

extern printf,putchar
global main

SECTION .data
    str1    DB  10h,0Dh,'Stampata in un solo colpo',10,0
    str2    DD  10h,0Dh,'Stampata byte per byte',10,0
    fine    DB  10h,0Dh,'Programma terminato',10,0

SECTION .text
main:   
    PUSH    str1
    CALL    printf
    POP EAX

    MOV ESI,str2     ;changed the register
    CLD         ;direction flag=0

stampa: LODSB
    CMP AX,0        ;at the end of string jump to end
    JE  end
    PUSH    AX
    CALL    putchar
    JMP     stampa

end:    PUSH    fine
    CALL    printf
    POP     EAX
```

Now the output is this:

```
Stampata in un solo colpo
Programma terminato
Errore di segmentazione (core dump creato)
```

Comment: Look at the prototype for `printf()`.

Comment: I've already read about printf(), I was trying to learn about the use of LODSB instruction, in fact I want to print the first string character by character and the second (final string) in a single block.
If I jump directly to the final string I don't get the error

Comment: `printf() != putchar()`. Do I really need to explain this further?

Comment: I've tryed even with putchar() but I still get the segmentation fault

Comment: Ah. `LODSB` doesn't load from `EDI`, it loads from `ESI` (which makes sense, it loads from `source index`, not from `destination index`).

Comment: Ooops, I've changet that line with: MOV ESI,str2 
Now it jump directly to the final line and then give me the segmentation fault (I've updated the code in the question)

Comment: You're not restoring the stack-pointer after the call to `putchar()`.

Comment: `lodsb` loads a byte into `al`, but you are comparing `ax` with 0. You should be doing `cmp al, 0`. Or better, since you're pushing an integer for the `putchar`, clear `ax` or `eax` each time before you call `lodsb`.

Comment: _"32bit assembly"_ vs. `CPU X64` ?